# Does changing log file location in IIS need a restart of websites?

Tags: iis, logging

i need to change to logfile location of several websites in IIS 7. But its a productive system and I cant restart/recycle any of them. So my question: Does the IIS needs a restart for the changes to take effect? (Does it restart/recycle automatically?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the log file can be changed when IIS is running; no restart of the site, the app pools, or the service itself occurs.